# Uniform convergence: how to write it correctly

Tags: calculus, analysis, uniform-convergence

Is $f_{n}\underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }f$
equivalent to $f_{n}\left( x\right) \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{%
\longrightarrow }f\left( x\right) $ ?

When we have a sequence of functions $\left( f_{n}\right) _{n\in \mathbb{N}}$
that converges uniformly to $f,$ we depict this by $f_{n}\underset{%
n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }f.$ Is it ok if we also write $%
f_{n}\left( x\right) \underset{n\rightarrow \infty }{\longrightarrow }%
f\left( x\right) $ ? I have a feeling something is not exactly right.

Comment: You should also define what your first notation is (there are many convergence notions of functions) but I would never read your second notation as uniform convergence, as $f_n(x), f(x)$ are concrete elements, not functions.

Comment: @QiZhu: In the second paragraph, "we depict this by..." defines it as uniform convergence.

Comment: Basically, this is a question of notation. Notation is written for clarity, and whatever notation you use, you should be clear what you mean. There is no “standard” notation that I know for uniform convergence - even the notation you’ve used here. But if there is no risk of confusion by your reader, you *could* use notation this way.

Comment: If you have only encountered pointwise and uniform convergence, you might think it is enough to have two notations, but there are a lot of definitions for function convergence $f_n\to f.$ Thus we tend to use words rather than notation to talk about types of function convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Notation itself has no meaning until one *defines* it. There is no "the" right way to write anything. There are *conventions* to follow though.

One usually describes uniform convergence as

> $f_n\to f$ *uniformly* as $n\to\infty$.

One writes "point-wise" convergence as

> For every $x$ (in the domain), $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ as $n\to\infty$.

or simply says

> $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise everywhere in the domain.

---

> Is it OK if we also write ...

One rarely uses such notation for uniform convergence.

Comment: But you surely can also write “$f_n(x)\to f(x)$ uniformly.” Or something like: “$\sum_{k=0}^n x^n\to\frac1{1-x}$ uniformly on $[-a,a]$ for any $a\in(0,1).$” I think the question is whether the notation allows explicit $x,$ but the reality is the notation is non-standard, and we prefer language to notation when talking about function convergence.